# rails 3.1 assets pipeline + acceptance test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, cucumber, asset-pipeline

we have a rather extensive acceptance test suite, running on our CI server triggered by a Github push hook. i'd like to add a feature or spec to basically test wether `rake assets:precompile` runs smoothly. we run this task usually in a capistrano callback, but it has happened, that, for whatever reason, some assets couldn't/wouldn't be precompiled, and i missed the warning in that painfully cluttered capistrano output. in my opinion, it would make sense if this breaks a build in our CI.
now my question is, is anybody doing that? is there a 'standard' or easy solution? is there something more comprehensive than just invoking the rake task with `should_not raise_error ...`?